# 301 redirect from one website to another using asp.net web.config file

Tags: asp.net, redirect, seo

I have an HTML page in my old website which needs 301 redirect to the aspx page of new website, both websites have been built on asp.net platform. Please suggest me that how could I configure my web.config file to achieve this task. 
At the moment I am using Meta Refresh to do this, but that is possibly 200 not 301.

Any help would be highly appreciated,Thanks.

I have used following piece of code in my old website web.config file, but it isn't working as well

```
<configuration>
  <location path="http://example.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://newwebsite.com/test.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create rules in your web.config file put

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^abc.html" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="Your current page path" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: +1 Does this work without any special modules or features added or installed?

Comment: Your code is fine for normal urls but I can't specify any query string in the url as IDE is giving error at compile time. For example I want to redirect to -  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/?area=90&startDay=31/12/2014" redirectType="Permanent" />

Comment: add one more tag between <match> and <action> tag <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="area=3&startday=31/12/2014" />
          </conditions>

Comment: @Nathaniel : yes you need to install Redirection tool on iis if not installed

Comment: I get an error. The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'rewrite'.

Answer (score 4):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://uri" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Sorry I don't have a web.config solution for single page. You'll want to place this in your markup page near the top:

```
<% RedirectPermanent("http://url", true) %>
```

If it doesn't work for you post your markup here and I'll update it for you.

Comment: where should I specify the old url which needs to be redirect

Comment: Are you trying to only redirect a single uri? The above redirects all requests for the domain. You can turn on childOnly if your destination needs to know the source. Otherwise if you only want to redirect a single Uri we need a different solution.

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect a single uri

Comment: I can see destination url but where is source url or which url to redirect ??

Comment: You place the code in the page (probably .aspx) that you'd like to redirect. This solution is not a configuration solution.